# Why does the reduce implementation return undefined method + for nil:NilClass once a boolean check returns true

Tags: ruby

I need to find the sum of all numbers which are equal to the sum of the factorial of their digits. I have an algorithm:

```
def equal_to_sum_of_factorial_digits?(n)
  n == n.to_s.scan(/\d/).map{|s| s.to_i}.reduce{|acc,j| (j == 0 || j == 1) ? 1 : acc + (1..j).inject(:*)}
end

start = Time.now
answer = (10..145).reduce {|acc,j| acc + j if equal_to_sum_of_factorial_digits?(j)}

puts "The answer is #{answer} and it took #{(Time.now-start)*1000} milliseconds."
```

Here the `equal_to_sum_of_factorial_digits?` makes a number into separate digits, then adds  value `1` if it is `1` or `0` (1 or 0 factorial is 1) or the factorial value if it is `2` up to `9`. The answer then sums all values in a range that have that property.

The code works until I go higher than 145 (145 is the first value which has the property that it is equal to the sum of its factorial digits: 145 = 1! + 4! + 5!) it gives the error `undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass`.

I have no idea why the code after `answer =` fails once the `equal_to_sum_of_factorial_digits?` method returns `true`. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: You don't have to handle the `j == 1` case exceptionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because in the previous iterations in `reduce`, the `acc` had been `nil` due to the block being evaluated to `nil`. Notice that the value of `acc` is the evaluated value of the block for each iteration.

Comment: Oh of course. I have to keep `acc` if the equal_to_sum_of_factorial_digits? returns false. This works: `answer = (10..145).reduce(0) {|acc,j| equal_to_sum_of_factorial_digits?(j) ? acc + j : acc}`. Thanks a lot!